# Hibernate is a wrapper over JDBC?

Tags: hibernate

JDBC is a protocol to execute queries in java. it has a set of classes n interfaces to connect to your database and query it.

**Hibernate is a wrapper over JDBC** which does everything said above and much more. For starters, mapping the results of a query directly into your java objects and allowing result caching, richer query language, efficient query functions and lot more.

This answer finded in Quora. i am confuse about this text bold. I don't think so. Can you explain about this?

Answer (score 0):

The bold text is absolutely wrong. A good explanation for Hibernate is on the Wiki page:

> Hibernate ORM (Hibernate in short) is an object-relational mapping
>   tool for the Java programming language. It provides a framework for
>   mapping an object-oriented domain model to a relational database.
>   Hibernate handles object-relational impedance mismatch problems by
>   replacing direct, persistent database accesses with high-level object
>   handling functions.
>
> [...]
>
> Hibernate's primary feature is mapping from Java classes to database
>   tables, and mapping from Java data types to SQL data types. Hibernate
>   also provides data query and retrieval facilities. It generates SQL
>   calls and relieves the developer from the manual handling and object
>   conversion of the result set.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)